# Cannot remove Bittorrent Sync from Mac

Tags: macos, bittorrent

I've removed the app from the Applications folder. I've removed the Library files for it.

A search of my Mac finds nothing named "bittorrent".

Still, when I restart my Mac, it shows back up again as an active process and asks me if I want to upgrade to the latest version.

This is starting to feel like a virus. How do I get rid of it entirely?

Answer (score 0):

which version of OS X are you running? It's possible that there's still a trace in your startup items folder. I'm using Yosemite, and if I go: Finder-Go-Go to folder and then type in /Library/StartupItems, it takes me to the folder with the startup items in. Alternatively, go to System Prefs - Users & Groups and click on your user name. Then click on the 'Login Items' tab to see if BT unpacked anything there. From what I remember, when installing BT there was a check box you could use to select if you wanted BT to fire up when you logged in or not. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I don't have a `Library/StartupItems` folder. Where else would I look?

Comment: Hi, which version of OS X are you running? I'm using Yosemite, and if I go: Finder-Go-Go to folder and then type in /Library/StartupItems, it takes me to the folder with the startup items in. Alternatively, go to System Prefs - Users & Groups and click on your user name. Then click on the 'Login Items' tab to see if BT unpacked anything there. From what I remember, when installing BT there was a check box you could use to select if you wanted BT to fire up when you logged in or not. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Ah perfect! That allowed me to track down the location. It was in my `Caskroom` files. I removed it there and also removed it from my brew dotfiles. Completely forgot I installed it via that method years ago! :) Could you update your answer please and I will accept.